# python- why the list doesn't modified?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> c=[1,100,3]
>>>def nullity (lst):
   lst=[]
>>>nullity (c)
>>>c
[1,100,3]
```

Why c doesn't return []? Isn't `nullity(c)` mean `c=lst` so thy both point now at []?

Comment: Am I the only one why thinks the asker haven't done their homework on this one? It has been asked so many times, why another one?

Comment: I think this question has been asked many times, but it is hard to formulate when doing a search query.

Answer (score 5):

Python has pass-by-value semantics, meaning that when you pass a parameter to a function, it receives a copy to the object's reference, but not the object itself. So, if you reassign a function parameter to something else (as you did), the assignment is *local* to the function, the original object "outside" the function remains unchanged. A completely different situation happens if you change something *inside* the object:

```
def test(a):
    a[0] = 0

lst = [1, 2, 3]
test(lst)
lst
=> [0, 2, 3]
```

In the above snippet the list's elements were changed, that's because both `lst` and `a` are pointing to the exact same object. Now back to the original question - notice that in Python 3.2 and below there isn't a `clear()` method (it was added in Python 3.3), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401933/why-is-there-no-list-clear-method-in-python) is a related discussion. But you can do this for the same effect, and it'll work in Python 2.x and 3.x:

```
def nullity(lst):
    del lst[:]
```

Comment: While the OP is using [tag:python-3.x], there's a chance that the `.clear()` method exists (implemented in Python 3.3)

Comment: @MaximeLorant that's news for me! fair enough, I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You're reassigning local variable `lst` to a *new* empty `list`. To empty an existing list, you need to delete all its members:

```
del lst[:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python does not allow you to replace parameters. You are only changing what "lst" refers to within the function, but it does not affect the calling code.

Instead change the list itself by clearing it:

```
def nullity (lst):
    lst.clear()  # With Python >= 3.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets use the [id()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#id) function

```
In [14]: c=[1,2,3]

In [15]: def nullity (lst):
    ...:     print id(lst)
    ...:     lst=[]
    ...:     print id(lst)
    ...:     

In [16]: id(c)
Out[16]: 33590520

In [17]: nullity(c)
33590520
33591024
```

When doing the reassignment a new local object is created which is not the same as the one used when calling the function.