# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy' in leetcode editor, but in my PyCharm it's no error

Tags: python

I'm using python to solve the 'Longest Common Prefix ' problem in leetcode. Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
# @param {string[]} strs
# @return {string}

def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs):


    if strs is None or strs == []:
        return ""


    if "" in strs:
        return ""



    minList=[]
    tempList=[]
    prefix=""



    if len(strs)>0:
        minLen = len(strs[0])
        for str in strs:
            if len(str)<minLen:
                minLen = len(str)

        for str in strs:
            if len(str)==minLen:
                minList.append(str)

    if len(minList)==1:
        prefix = minList[0]
    else:
        while True:
            isAllEqual = True

            for min in minList:
                if min!=minList[0]:
                    isAllEqual=False


            if isAllEqual:
                prefix=minList[0]
                break

            else:
                for min in minList:
                    tempList.append(min[:-1])

                minList.clear()
                minList=tempList.copy()
                tempList.clear()
    if prefix == "":
        return prefix


    for string in strs:

        if prefix in string:
            continue
        else:
            while prefix:


                prefix = prefix[:-1]

                if prefix =="":
                    return ""

                if prefix in string:

                    break

    return prefix
```

I make some testing in my PyCharm ,it's ok.
But when I ran it in leetcode
It gave me :

**Runtime Error Message:    Line 52: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'clear'
Last executed input:    ["a","b"]**

which line 52 is:

```
minList.clear()
```

I'm a rookie , Thank you for helping me!Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there no list.clear() method in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401933/why-is-there-no-list-clear-method-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python 3 `list` class has a `clear()` method, but the Python 2 `list` class does not. This is most likely the source of the problem. It seems that leetcode will run your script using Python 2, so you should develop it in Python 2 as well to avoid incompatibilities like this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using python2 interpreter to run this code which is python 3 code. There are several solution for this. 
You can use a [shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7670338/1113211) like,

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Or invoke the python3 interpreter in the terminal. like

```
$ python3 myscript.py
```