# How to check if a list exists in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a networkx graph.
I am adding nodes by adding edges

```
G.add_edge(route[i-1],route[i]);
```

Now once the node is created by directly adding edges,
I add a list named

```
G.node[route[i]]['position'] = list()
```

and I append positions to it when I get same nodes again and again

```
G.node[route[i]]['position'].append( i - 3 )
```

Now when I want to append how do I check whether the list exist?
does doing

```
G.node[route[i]]['position'] = list()
```

clear the list of already existing elements?

edit----- my earlier question was confusing
I want to keep adding to the list
but I cant append unless a list exists, right? 
So I have to do do 
 `G.node[route[i]]['position'] = list()` in my loop
So next time when I want to add to the same list in another loop instance how do I know that a list exists for `G.node[route[i]]['position']` and I dont have to create it again.

edit-----
I think my list itself is a key here
so I did

```
                    if not 'position' in G.node[route[i]]:
```

and it works

Comment: My python is rusty but I think doing `"position" in G.node[route[i]]` to look for the key. (assuming that position does not exist before you create the list())

Comment: for that  -- if not G.node[traceroute[i]]['position'] --
I get a invalid syntax

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood. I wasn't saying to do an `if not` condition. The "in" is an operator in Python. See this thread: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/614846-how-test-if-key-dictionary-exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`G.node[route[i]]['position'] = list()` will leave the slot `G.node[route[i]]['position']` holding an empty list, but it will not affect the list that it previously held, which other objects may have a reference to.

Instead, use: `del l[:]` to empty the list.

If you want to have a list automatically created, use `collections.defaultdict` to have newly created entries default to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that clears the existing list. You could try

```
G.node[route[i]].setdefault('position', []).append(...)
```

whenever you want to append elements.

Comment: Assigning a new list is not the same as clearing an existing list.

Comment: You've got a point there. The existing list is not cleared when one assigns a new list as the value in that dictionary. I focussed on the other aspect of the OP's question, i.e. checking whether `G.node[route[i]]['position']` already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but assigning list() should make sure that there is a list to append to. If there's already a list the assignment creates a new one (see answer of Marcin). Test:

```
>>> a = list()
>>> for i in range(10):
...     a.append(i)
...
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> b = a
>>> b
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a = list()
>>> a
[]
>>> b
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1) How do I check whether the list exist?

Use [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance) and do something like:

```
if not ininstance(G.node[route[i]]['position'], list):
    G.node[route[i]]['position'] = list()
G.node[route[i]]['position'].append(i - 3)
```

Or use `type` like:

```
if not type(G.node[route[i]]['position']) is list
```

I must say that this kind of checking is rather un-pythonic, usually you should know what `G.node[route[i]]['position']` was before becoming a list and check for that.

For example, if it was `None` you could do (assuming that the key 'position' exists, otherwise just call `get('position')`):

```
if G.node[route[i]]['position'] is None:
    G.node[route[i]]['position'] = list()
G.node[route[i]]['position'].append(i - 3)
```

#### 2) Does doing `.. = list()` clear the list of already existing elements?

The answer is No.

`list()` will instantiate a new empty list.

You may want to take a look at this SO question: [How to empty a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1400622/1132524).
In short:

```
G.node[route[i]]['position'][:] = []
```

will clear your list.

Comment: Why put a -1 like that? Just tell me if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Don't know who gave the -1. However I think you misunderstood OP question. Problem is G.node[route[i]] does not have 'position' as key at first iteration and all you suggested will fail with a 'KeyError'.

Comment: @Bogdan: I just assumed that he/she initialized that value before the loop, so I didn't thought of using `get` (like you did). I'll clear that now, thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Just use get:

```
    if G.node[route[i]].get('position') is None:
        G.node[route[i]]['position'] = list()
    else:
        G.node[route[i]]['position'].append(stuff)
```