# Is there a specific command to delete all elements of a list?

Tags: python, list

I know that you can simply:

```
list = [a, b, c, d, e]

for index in list:
    list.remove(index)
```

but is there a faster way with a single command like:

```
list.remove(all)
```

or something along those lines?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400608/how-to-empty-a-list-in-python

Comment: Searched and didn't find it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of:

```
myList[:] = []
```

Or another way can be assigning `None` to the list, the garbage collector will free up the memory eventually.

("list" is not a good name for a `list` in python, it's already a type)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) and [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation):

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> del lst[:]
>>> lst
[]
>>>
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> id(lst)
34212720
>>> del lst[:]
>>> id(lst)  # Note that the list object remains the same
34212720
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do `del myList[:]`.  (Don't use `list` as a variable name, it blocks access to the builtin type called `list`.)