# Increase in memory usage on pandas dataframe creation

Tags: python, pandas, memory

I have a piece of code which receives call-back from another function and creates a list of list (pd_arr). This list is then used to create a data frame. Finally the list of list is deleted.

On profiling using memory-profiler, this is the output

```
102.632812 MiB   0.000000 MiB       init()
236.765625 MiB 134.132812 MiB           add_to_list()
                                    return pd.DataFrame()
394.328125 MiB 157.562500 MiB       pd_df = pd.DataFrame(pd_arr, columns=df_columns)
350.121094 MiB -44.207031 MiB       pd_df = pd_df.set_index(df_columns[0])
350.292969 MiB   0.171875 MiB       pd_df.memory_usage()
350.328125 MiB   0.035156 MiB       print sys.getsizeof(pd_arr), sys.getsizeof(pd_arr[0]), sys.getsizeof(pd_df), len(pd_arr)
350.328125 MiB   0.000000 MiB       del pd_arr
```

On checking deep memory usage of pd_df (data frame), it is 80.5 MB. So, my question is why does the memory not decrement after `del pd_arr` line.

Also, total data frame size as per profiler (157 - 44 = 110 MB) seems to be more than 80 MB. So, what causes the difference?

Also, is there any other memory-efficient way to create data frame (data received in loop) which is not too bad in time performance (For eg: increment of 10s of seconds should be fine for data-frame of size 100MB)?

Edit: Simple python script which explains this behaviour

```
Filename: py_test.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     9    102.0 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    10                             def setup():
    11                              global arr, size
    12    102.0 MiB      0.0 MiB    arr = range(1, size)
    13    131.2 MiB     29.1 MiB    arr = [x+1 for x in arr]


Filename: py_test.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    21    131.2 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    22                             def tearDown():
    23                              global arr
    24    131.2 MiB      0.0 MiB    del arr[:]
    25    131.2 MiB      0.0 MiB    del arr
    26     93.7 MiB    -37.4 MiB    gc.collect()
```

On introducing dataframe,

```
Filename: py_test.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     9    102.0 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    10                             def setup():
    11                              global arr, size
    12    102.0 MiB      0.0 MiB    arr = range(1, size)
    13    132.7 MiB     30.7 MiB    arr = [x+1 for x in arr]


Filename: py_test.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    15    132.7 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    16                             def dfCreate():
    17                              global arr
    18    147.1 MiB     14.4 MiB    pd_df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
    19    147.1 MiB      0.0 MiB    return pd_df


Filename: py_test.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    21    147.1 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    22                             def tearDown():
    23                              global arr
    24                              #del arr[:]
    25    147.1 MiB      0.0 MiB    del arr
    26    147.1 MiB      0.0 MiB    gc.collect()
```

Comment: Are you completely sure there is not a reference to `pd_arr` anywhere else in the code? Python is reference-counted, so using `del` will only free the associated memory if it can be ensured that the deleted object cannot be used from anywhere. You can also try to [clear the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400608/how-to-empty-a-list-in-python).

Comment: I tried using `del pd_arr[:]`. No memory is reduced. pd_arr is defined as global in the code. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Well `del pd_arr` just means that you cannot use the name `pd_arr` to refer to that list anymore, whether global or not, but if at some previous point there was something like `a = pd_arr` (although it could be something much more subtle, like passing `pd_arr` to a function and having its reference copied somewhere else), then it will not be really deleted. However, I cannot explain why `del pd_arr[:]` does not make any difference.

Comment: There is no other reference pointer to pd_arr as such.

Answer (score 4):

Answering your first question, when you try to clean out memory using `del pd_arr` actually this doesn't happen because `DataFrame` stores one link to `pd_arr`, and top scope keeps one more link; decreasing refcounter won't collect memory, because this memory is under use.

You may check my assumption by running `sys.getrefcount(pd_arr)` before `del pd_arr` and you will get `2` as a result.

Now, I believe that the following code snippet does the same what you're trying to do: https://gist.github.com/vladignatyev/ec7a26b7042efd6f710d436afbfb87de/90df8cc6bbb8bd0cb3a1d2670e03aff24f3a5b24

If you try this snippet, you will see the memory usage as follows:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    13   63.902 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
    14                             def to_profile():
    15  324.828 MiB  260.926 MiB       pd_arr = make_list()
    16                                 # pd_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(pd_arr, columns=[x for x in range(0,1000)])
    17  479.094 MiB  154.266 MiB       pd_df = pd.DataFrame(pd_arr)
    18                                 # pd_df.info(memory_usage='deep')
    19  479.094 MiB    0.000 MiB       print sys.getsizeof(pd_arr), sys.getsizeof(pd_arr[0])
    20  481.055 MiB    1.961 MiB       print sys.getsizeof(pd_df), len(pd_arr)
    21  481.055 MiB    0.000 MiB       print sys.getrefcount(pd_arr)
    22  417.090 MiB  -63.965 MiB       del pd_arr
    23  323.090 MiB  -94.000 MiB       gc.collect()
```

Try this example:

```
@profile
def test():
    a = [x for x in range(0,100000)]
    del a


aa = test()
```

You will get exactly what you expect:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     6   64.117 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     7                             def test():
     8   65.270 MiB    1.152 MiB       a = [x for x in range(0,100000)]
     9                                 # print sys.getrefcount(a)
    10   64.133 MiB   -1.137 MiB       del a
    11   64.133 MiB    0.000 MiB       gc.collect()
```

Also, if you call `sys.getrefcount(a)`, the memory sometimes will be cleaned before `del a`:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     6   63.828 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     7                             def test():
     8   65.297 MiB    1.469 MiB       a = [x for x in range(0,100000)]
     9   64.230 MiB   -1.066 MiB       print sys.getrefcount(a)
    10   64.160 MiB   -0.070 MiB       del a
```

**But things go wild when you use `pandas`.**

If you open the source code of `pandas.DataFrame`, you will see, that in the case when you initialize `DataFrame` with `list`, `pandas` creates new NumPy array and copies it's content. Check this out: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L329

Deleting `pd_arr` won't free the memory, because `pd_arr` will be collected after `DataFrame` creation and exiting your function anyway, since it doesn't have any additional links to it. `getrefcount` call before and after proves this.

Creating new `DataFrame` from plain list make your list copied with NumPy Array. (Look at `np.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)` and the corresponding documentation about `array`) 
Copying operation may affect the time of execution, because allocating new memory block is a heavy operation.

I've tried to initialize new DataFrame with Numpy array instead. The only difference is where `numpy.Array` memory overhead appears. Compare the following two snippets:

```
def make_list():  # 1
    pd_arr = []
    for i in range(0,10000):
        pd_arr.append([x for x in range(0,1000)])
    return np.array(pd_arr)
```

and

```
def make_list():  #2
    pd_arr = []
    for i in range(0,10000):
        pd_arr.append([x for x in range(0,1000)])
    return pd_arr
```

Number #1 (creating DataFrame doesn't produce Memory Usage Overhead!):

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    14   63.672 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
    15                             def to_profile():
    16  385.309 MiB  321.637 MiB       pd_arr = make_list()
    17  385.309 MiB    0.000 MiB       print sys.getrefcount(pd_arr)
    18  385.316 MiB    0.008 MiB       pd_df = pd.DataFrame(pd_arr)
    19  385.316 MiB    0.000 MiB       print sys.getsizeof(pd_arr), sys.getsizeof(pd_arr[0])
    20  386.934 MiB    1.617 MiB       print sys.getsizeof(pd_df), len(pd_arr)
    21  386.934 MiB    0.000 MiB       print sys.getrefcount(pd_arr)
    22  386.934 MiB    0.000 MiB       del pd_arr
    23  305.934 MiB  -81.000 MiB       gc.collect()
```

Number #2 (over 100Mb overhead due to copying of array)!:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    14   63.652 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
    15                             def to_profile():
    16  325.352 MiB  261.699 MiB       pd_arr = make_list()
    17  325.352 MiB    0.000 MiB       print sys.getrefcount(pd_arr)
    18  479.633 MiB  154.281 MiB       pd_df = pd.DataFrame(pd_arr)
    19  479.633 MiB    0.000 MiB       print sys.getsizeof(pd_arr), sys.getsizeof(pd_arr[0])
    20  481.602 MiB    1.969 MiB       print sys.getsizeof(pd_df), len(pd_arr)
    21  481.602 MiB    0.000 MiB       print sys.getrefcount(pd_arr)
    22  417.621 MiB  -63.980 MiB       del pd_arr
    23  330.621 MiB  -87.000 MiB       gc.collect()
```

So, initialize `DataFrame` only with Numpy Array, not a `list`. It is better from the memory consumption perspective and probably faster, because it doesn't require additional memory allocation call.

Hopefully, now I've answered all of your questions.

Comment: I tried to compute ref counts before and after dataframe creation.
[Code-link](https://gist.github.com/Rajlaxmi/eae3708fc1fd0d6cca24d6003be61539)
. Ref count was 2 before and after data frame creation.

Comment: I see the same. I'm trying to understand what's wrong.

Comment: It's okay that ref count is 2. 
>>> import sys
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> print sys.getrefcount(a)
2

Comment: @Rajs123 please check my answer! You have to prefer np.array over list during the DataFrame creation because it's faster and doesn't require additional data copying, that occur in `pandas` internals (proof is in the answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was everything I needed. Also, Thanks for pointing out the code. Will be using it a lot now :)