# Difference between list = [] vs. list.clear()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

What is the difference between `list = []` and `list.clear()`?

Base on the behavior of my code and my own observation, `list.clear()` removes its entries and also the entries I used to append its data.

Example:

```
container.append(list)
list.clear()
```

`container` will also be `[]`

Comment: What would happen if two different variables hold the *same* list value ?

Comment: It sounds like you may want to read about [the relationship between objects and variables in Python](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to empty a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400608/how-to-empty-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Calling `clear` removes all the element from the list. Assigning `[]` just replaces that variable with another empty list. This becomes evident when you have two variables pointing to the same list.

Consider the following snippet:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = l1
>>> l1.clear()
>>> l1 # l1 is obviously empty
[]
>>> l2 # But so is l2, since it's the same object
[]
```

As compared to this one:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = l1
>>> l1 = []
>>> l1 # l1 is obviously empty
[]
>>> l2 # But l2 still points to the previous value, and is not affected
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also see this if you take a look at the bytecode that is generated. Here the part with `x = []`

```
import dis

print("Example with x = []")

s1 = """
x = [1,2,3]
x = []
"""

dis.dis(s1)
```

which outputs

```
Exmaple with x = []
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
              6 BUILD_LIST               3
              8 STORE_NAME               0 (x)

  3          10 BUILD_LIST               0
             12 STORE_NAME               0 (x)
             14 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

we can see that two lists are build since we have two `BUILD_LIST`. Now if we take a look at `x.clear()`

```
print("Exmaple with x.clear()")

s2 = """
x = [1,2,3]
x.clear()
"""

dis.dis(s2)
```

we get the following output

```
Exmaple with x.clear()
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
              6 BUILD_LIST               3
              8 STORE_NAME               0 (x)

  3          10 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                1 (clear)
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             16 POP_TOP
             18 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

and here only one list is build and clear is called and `LOAD_CONST` is used to place `None` onto the stack as with the initial values `1,2,3`.

Comment: Would `x = []` be significantly faster than `x.clear()`? Especially if `x` has a lot of elements to being with.